# understand non-blocking in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Trying to undertand non-blocking in nodejs, I made the code as following: looping the elements in a array, for each of the element, "sleep" for a while before log the element. Expected all console.log should be execute very close since it's not blocking by the sleep, but not actually: where goes wrong here?

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    data.push(i);
}

function sleep(milliSeconds, callback) {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
}

var print = function(content) {
    sleep(1000, function(){
        callback();
    });
    console.log(String(content) + ': ' + String((new Date()).getTime()));
};

for (var item in data) {
    print(item);
}
```

Comment: Uh, your `sleep` function *is* blocking???

Comment: What is `callback`? Why is it never called? Why don't you use `setTimeout`?

Comment: All javascript execution is blocking in node.js, other things can be eg `fs.readFileSync` but don't have to be eg `fs.readFile`.  Your code example is all javascript execution, and thus all blocking.

Comment: thanks @Bergi, previously I thought using sleep to _pretend_ the function as a time consuming task, based on this I was trying to understand the non-blocking in node.js

Comment: Non-blocking in node.js usually means "time-consuming but asynchronous". You need to use an api that is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop in your `sleep` method is blocking. NodeJS has a [built in method](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) for that. Also, you need to log inside the callback, not immediately after the sleep call. Updated code might look something like this:

```
    var data = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {
        data.push( i );
    }

    var printContent = function( content ) {
    //use built-in method to run function after 5000 milliseconds
        setTimeout( function() {
            console.log( String( content ) + ': ' + String( ( new Date() ).getTime() ) );
        }, 5000 );
    };

    //different way to loop over an array, better than var...in for the Array type
    data.forEach( function( item ) {
        printContent( item );
    } );
```